# Is Panini #ifequal can evaluate object 'this'?

Tags: handlebars.js, zurb-foundation

I work with the ZURB template of Foundation for sites.

I really can't find what is the problem and can't be sure if "this" can be passing to the helper `#ifequal` (Panini). The partial where the code is :

```
        {{#each @root.content}}
          {{#ifequal @key @../key}}
              {{@key}}-{{this}} this output the right key and string 'import-fragment'
            {{#ifequal this 'import-fragment'}} but never evaluate it equal to true?
              {{@key}}-{{this}} nothing here and never call this partial
              {{> fragment-router sub-segment-obj=../this }}
            {{else}}
              all works well from here
              {{> main-content sub-segment-obj=../this }}
            {{/ifequal}}
          {{/ifequal}}
        {{/each}}
```

as you can see in the code, I'm not able to get the string 'import-fragment' = to true `{{#ifequal this 'import-fragment'}}` even if it's the right string that is evaluated. This is the page where I put content in Front Matter YAML format :

```
---
  category: marketing

  content:
  ###################################### SECTION ########################################## 

    web-stats: import-fragment # why this doesn't equal import-fragment???

  # all following this works
    web-stats-in-page-way:
      sub-sections:

  ################### ARTICLE #######################      

        First article:
  ...
```

Is someone can see what I missed?

Thank you in advance. I will payback to the next.

Comment: Did you figure this out yet?

Comment: Nope, I put 'import-fragment' as key of the object­ and I can test it, but I would like to know why that's not working the other way.